# PostgreSQL check if array contains any value from list

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL to check if any values from a certain list are in any of the arrays stored in a database.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') = ANY(field_name);
```

`field_name` is a `VARCHAR(100)[]`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `field_name` is an array, you can use the [overlaps operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) `&&`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE field_name && array['value1', 'value2', 'value3']::varchar[]
```

Comment: Seems like VARCHAR and text are incompatible to compare, but this is definitely a step in the right direction!

Comment: @pteixeira: then cast the array to `varchar[]`

Comment: Got to it eventually; waiting on timer to accept answer. Thank you!